# Add an external font in css using file of type .File

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, font-family

Is it possible to add an external font in css using file of type `.File`?

Here is what I tried with no luck:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: AvenirHeavy;
    src: url("fonts\AvenirLT\AvenirLT-Heavy.tff");
}
.applyFont {
    font-family: AvenirHeavy;
}
```

Also I tried this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: AvenirHeavy;
    src: url("fonts\AvenirLT\AvenirLT-Heavy.File");
}
.applyFont {
    font-family: AvenirHeavy;
}
```

Here are the details about the font:

[image]

And for some reasons ide (WebStorm) does not know about font inclusion and tells me that it `Cannot resolve file`:

[image]

The first four characters are:
`NUL NUL NUL NUL`.
[image]

Comment: Given that `.File` is not a real font extension in the slightest, you will need to tell the CSS engine what kind of font this is supposed to even be. Add a source `format` parameter in addition to your `url`. But the proper solution is to rename your font to its normal name. Don't call fonts `.File`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, it does not help. I do not know the actual type behind `.File` type. I just know for sure that I was provided with a font file.

Comment: Then how do you know it's even a font at all? Because "someone told me it was" is not knowing this file is a font: they could have sent you weirdly packed file, or encrypted it, or sent a generator's config file by mistake, etc. etc. Check the first four bytes of the file. Are they "00 01 00 00" (which'll look like nothing), "4F 54 54 4F" (which spells "OTTO"), or "74 74 63 66" (which spells "ttcf")?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, how can I do that? When I open file with `Notepad++` I am seeing only a long line of repeating word `NULL`.

Comment: View > Show Symbols > Show all characters. What does it say the first four are?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I updated the question. Thank you.

Comment: Uhh.. you updated it with a picture that literally hides the first four characters. So instead of posting a picture, can you _type_ what the first four characters are (don't try to copy-paste, just type it)? Because that's not an arbitrary question: the OpenType specification dictates that the first four bytes say which kind of font this is. If they don't match any of the allowed values, then this is not a font.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, the characters `copy-paste` to an empty space. ) :

Comment: Like I said, **don't** try to copy-paste, just type it over by hand. If it's NUL SOH NUL NUL we're dealing with a `.ttf` file that has the wrong extension. If it's something else, that something else can tell us what kind of file we're (possibly) dealing with.